How to customize for AWS SES Verification mail?
We wish to allow our product users to send emails to their clients, from our platform.
We're using AWS SES for this.
According to the docs, we need to verify the email of our product users before being able to send emails from their id. The docs has comprehensive guide for triggering these emails programatically, and we're able to verify our user's emails sucessfully.
However, the default emails being sent by AWS SES is not at all user friendly, at least to our non techie clients. So we're using Custom Verification Email templates. Here's a snapshot of the a sample custom email (taken from docs):

Even though we can modify this template to make it more user friendly (using html), there doesn't appear any way of replacing that verification link by a button.
The question:

How to replace the email verification link, sent by AWS SES, to a more user friendly design, like a button? The idea is, The user clicks that button, which in effect calls this link to verify user's email. Something like this:


So far from my readings, I figured that there are no ways by which AWS shares this link to anyone other than the intended email owner, for obvious reasons. Also, this link (and the last line) are automatically added at the end of the custom email template we create.
Possibly unrelated: my servers are running on Java Spring boot, and uses AWS Java SDK (v2) for triggering these verification mails.

It's a bit unclear what the issue you're having is.  The link you include shows how to send HTML mail and button is an explicitly allowed tag.  Where are you running into problems?

@stdunbarbutton tag is allowed, however, we don't have access to the link. What to provide in href?
